# Create C# application using Windows 8 metro interface

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, windows-store-apps

I have created a C# Windows Form application. Is it possible for me to convert it into a Windows 8 Metro like interface with the same GUI animations and stuff? Please advice. If I can't convert the existing one, how can I make a new one using C#?

Comment: While you can't convert the WinForms project directly, it's possible that you can reuse a lot of the logic. This link can help you get started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh974581.aspx

Comment: But this is for Windows Store App right? Will it work out for desktop applications as well? Please help.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you'd still like a desktop app, but one that looks and feels like a store app? If so, you may want to look at plain WPF.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I need. Is that look and feel available in WPF?

Comment: Not directly, no, though I imagine you could imitate the style with a little work.

Comment: ok..thanks a lot. I will look into some tutorials. Please share any links if you know any.

Comment: well windows 8 app are called metro app. simply search for Metro style on your app. on WPF i have metro style on every control from syncfusion so there must be control look override people have done. unless the winform syncfusion also have metro app style but i doudt our license is for winform too.

Comment: Not sure what you have that needs to be done, but there's a library that aims to give a Metro "feel" to WinForms. You could replace your standard WinForm controls with the equivalent MetroForms: http://www.nuget.org/packages/ModernUI/

Comment: @glace I tried nuget. But I the form still looks like normal Windows Form. Only the controls have changed. Is there a way to change the form design as well? I am also getting a null reference exception at  this.metroStyleManager2.OwnerForm = null; but when I add try/catch it doesn't cause any breaks. Could that be a problem as well?

Answer (score 0):

Download the Nuget package manager from this link and install the metro ui. Then you will get a folder named 'package' in your project. Then got to visual studio and right click on general and select 'add items' Then browse for the 'packages' folder and select the metro ui library. Now you will get the metro controls. As long as the title bar is concerned you will have to change it manually. You could disable the current one and create your own.

http://www.nuget.org/packages/ModernUI/